# unite lists if at least one value matches in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a list of lists, for example:

```
[[0, 2], [0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 7, 8], [6, 4]]
```

and if at least one of the values on a list is the same that another one of a different list, i would like to unite the lists so in the example the final result would be:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

I really don't care about the order of the values inside the list `[0, 1, 2, 3]` or `[0, 2, 1, 3]`.

I tried to do it but it doesn't work. So have you got any ideas? Thanks.

Edit(sorry for not posting the code that i tried before):
What i tried to do was the following:

```
for p in llista:
        for q in p:
            for k in llista:
                if p==k:
                    llista.remove(k)
                else:
                    for h in k:
                        if p!=k:
                            if q==h:
                                k.remove(h)
                                for t in k:
                                    if t not in p:
                                        p.append(t)
    llista_final = [x for x in llista if x != []]
```

Where **llista** is the list of lists.

Comment: "_I tried to do it but it doesn't work._" Please include your code.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to mutate the list you are iterating over.

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit this is a tricky problem. I'm really curious what does this problem represent and/or where did you find it out...

I initially have thought this is just a *graph connected components* problem, but I wanted to take a shortcut from creating an explicit representation of the graph, running bfs, etc...

The idea of the solution is this: for every sublist, check if it has some common element with any other sublist, and replace that with their union.

Not very pythonic, but here it is:

```
def merge(l):
    l = list(map(tuple, l))
    for i, h in enumerate(l):
        sh = set(h)
        for j, k in enumerate(l):
            if i == j: continue
            sk = set(k)
            if sh & sk: # h and k have some element in common
                l[j] = tuple(sh | sk)
    return list(map(list, set(l)))
```

Comment: I'll try this , but now i can't cos i'm not at home. I'll tell you if it works, i did something similar but had something wrong I think and didn't work.

Comment: This is from a problem of particles in a box, at the beginning i scan all the coordinates of the particles and if the distance from the particle A to the particle B is smaller than a certain number then i generate a list [A,B] so at the beginning I only have lists of 2 numbers [[A,B],[C,D],[J,Z],...] but it happens that this particles agregate with each other forming chains, and i have to count the number of chains and it's length.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that does what you want. I tried to use self-documenting variable names and comments to help you understand how this code works. As far as I can tell, the code is pythonic. I used sets to speed up and simplify some of the operations. The downside of that is that the items in your input list-of-lists must be hashable, but your example uses integers which works perfectly well.

```
def cliquesfromlistoflists(inputlistoflists):
    """Given a list of lists, return a new list of lists that unites
    the old lists that have at least one element in common.
    """
    listofdisjointsets = []
    for inputlist in inputlistoflists:
        # Update the list of disjoint sets using the current sublist
        inputset = set(inputlist)
        unionofsetsoverlappinginputset = inputset.copy()
        listofdisjointsetsnotoverlappinginputset = []
        for aset in listofdisjointsets:
            # Unite set if overlaps the new input set, else just store it
            if aset.isdisjoint(inputset):
                listofdisjointsetsnotoverlappinginputset.append(aset)
            else:
                unionofsetsoverlappinginputset.update(aset)
        listofdisjointsets = (listofdisjointsetsnotoverlappinginputset 
                              + [unionofsetsoverlappinginputset])
    # Return the information in a list-of-lists format
    return [list(aset) for aset in listofdisjointsets]

print(cliquesfromlistoflists([[0, 2], [0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 7, 8], [6, 4]]))
# printout is [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution modifies the generic breadth-first search to gradually diminish the initial `deque` and update a `result` list with either a combination should a match be found or a list addition if no grouping is discovered:

```
from collections import deque
d = deque([[0,2] , [0,1] , [2,3] , [4,5,7,8] , [6,4]])
result = [d.popleft()]
while d:
  v = d.popleft()
  result = [list(set(i+v)) if any(c in i for c in v) else i for i in result] if any(any(c in i for c in v) for i in result) else result + [v]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [8, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```